# Правильный namespace в xml c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialize, namespace

Имеется XML:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/addressing" 
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:MessageID>uuid:71a3676c-ff20-4eae-8ad6-34235a0c0c7c</wsa:MessageID>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      ...
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Из неё я генирирую C# класс, используя Edit-Paste Special-Paste XML As Classes в Visual Studio. Получается следующее:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Envelope
{
    private EnvelopeHeader headerField;
    private string bodyField;
    /// <remarks/>
    public EnvelopeHeader Header
    {
        get
        {
            return this.headerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.headerField = value;
        }
    }
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Body
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bodyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bodyField = value;
        }
    }
}
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public partial class EnvelopeHeader
{
    private string messageIDField;
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/addressing")]
    public string MessageID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.messageIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.messageIDField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

После создания экземпляра класса `Envelope` пытаюсь его сериализовать в строку.
Получаю следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<q1:Envelope xmlns:q1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Header xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <MessageID xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/addressing">uuid:00e7baf2-f019-4961-85ea-d63a5f93ce51</MessageID>
    </Header>
    <Body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        ....
    </Body>
</q1:Envelope>
```

Хотя ожидал получить первоначальную XML. 
Вопроса 2:
1) Что за дефолтный namespace q1?
2) Какие атрибуты следует добавить в C# код для получения необходимого результата?

Comment: Имя префикса не имеет значения, будь то `q1` или `soap`. Откуда взялось `envelopeeeeee` - возможно, в коде c# при использовании `XmlSerializer` задан неймспейс в таком виде?

Comment: `envelopeeeeee` случайно оказалось в этом коде, исправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обоих представленных xml неймспейсы правильные. Оба этих документы идентичные с точки зрения стандарта xml. Названия префиксов не играют никакой роли.

Однако, если очень хочется, то можно задать желаемые имена префиксам.

Максимально упрощу классы:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope
{
    public EnvelopeHeader Header { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class EnvelopeHeader
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/addressing")]
    public string MessageID { get; set; }
}
```

Этого вполне достаточно, чтобы `XmlSerializer` корректно работал с входным xml. Кстати, вы не написали, что именно используете. Я предположил, что это стандартный `XmlSerializer`.

```
Envelope envelope;

var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

// Десериализуем
using (var fs = new FileStream("in.xml", FileMode.Open))
    envelope = (Envelope)xs.Deserialize(fs);


var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
ns.Add("wsa", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/addressing");

// Сериализуем
using (var fs = new FileStream("out.xml", FileMode.Create))
    xs.Serialize(fs, envelope, ns);
```

Префиксы задаются с помощью класса `XmlSerializerNamespaces`. Передаём его экземпляр в метод `Serialize`.