# Ошибка при десериализации XML

Tags: c#, xml

Есть xml

```
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
   <NewDataSet>
      <Table>
         <AtomicNumber>1</AtomicNumber>
         <ElementName>Hydrogen</ElementName>
         <Symbol>H</Symbol>
         <AtomicWeight>1.00797</AtomicWeight>
         <BoilingPoint>20.400000000000002</BoilingPoint>
         <IonisationPotential>13.6</IonisationPotential>
         <EletroNegativity>2.2</EletroNegativity>
         <AtomicRadius>0.37</AtomicRadius>
         <MeltingPoint>14</MeltingPoint>
         <Density>0.08375</Density>
      </Table>
   </NewDataSet>
</string>
```

а вот этот код

```
string xml = requst
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parametres));
Parametres result;
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    result = (Parametres)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

при десериализации говорит

> "В документе XML(1,2) присутствует ошибка"

P.S. xml валидатором проверял

P.S.S код класса Parametres

```
using System.Reflection;
namespace PeriodicTable
{
    public class Parametres
    {
        public string AtomicNumber { get; set; }
        public string ElementName { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string AtomicWeight { get; set; }
        public string BoilingPoint { get; set; }
        public string IonisationPotential { get; set; }
        public string EletroNegativity { get; set; }
        public string AtomicRadius { get; set; }
        public string MeltingPoint { get; set; }
        public string Density { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вебсервис выдает "System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: ElementName.". Не похоже на валидный xml.

Comment: Создайте обьект - сериализируйте  - сравните xml. Где-то неверная структура.

Comment: @PashaPash я заменил ссылку, самим xml

Comment: @performance этот xml не похож на результат сериализации класса Parametres. У вас на классе Parametres прописан XmlRoot c правильным ElementName и Namespace? Покажите код класса Parameters целиком

Comment: @PashaPash добавил

Comment: @performance ваш класс не соответствует xml, который вы в него пытаетесь десериализовать. Надо или подгонять xml, или определять класс по-другому.

Comment: @PashaPash можно, пожалуйста, конкретней что требуется?

Comment: Вот вопрос по namespace https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654888/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-namespace-%d0%b2-xml-c

Comment: Вот вопрос с root-ом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483993/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-xml-%d0%b2-string-c

Answer (score 2):

Вам придется добавить классы-обертки для того, чтобы добраться до нужного элемента при десериализации (или вручную вырезать его из XML). Вариант с классами-обертками выглядит примерно так:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET", ElementName ="string")]
public class Response
{
    public NewDataSet NewDataSet { get; set; }
}

public class NewDataSet
{
    public Parametres Table { get; set; }
}

public class Parametres
{
    public byte AtomicNumber { get; set; }
    public string ElementName { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public decimal AtomicWeight { get; set; }
    public decimal BoilingPoint { get; set; }
    public decimal IonisationPotential { get; set; }
    public decimal EletroNegativity { get; set; }
    public decimal AtomicRadius { get; set; }
    public byte MeltingPoint { get; set; }
    public decimal Density { get; set; }
}

string xml = @"
<string xmlns=""http://www.webserviceX.NET"">
<NewDataSet> <Table> <AtomicNumber>1</AtomicNumber> <ElementName>Hydrogen</ElementName> <Symbol>H</Symbol> <AtomicWeight>1.00797</AtomicWeight> <BoilingPoint>20.400000000000002</BoilingPoint> <IonisationPotential>13.6</IonisationPotential> <EletroNegativity>2.2</EletroNegativity> <AtomicRadius>0.37</AtomicRadius> <MeltingPoint>14</MeltingPoint> <Density>0.08375</Density> </Table> </NewDataSet>
</string>";

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
Parametres result;
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    result = ((Response)serializer.Deserialize(reader)).NewDataSet.Table;
}
```

Comment: Та же самая ошибка(

Comment: @performance я проверял на том xml, что вы привели. если у вас "та же самая ошибка" - значит или у вас xml другой (request / response не перепутали?), или класс не так задан. Или вы код из моего ответа не целиком скопировали (например, тип не тот в new XmlSerializer() указали).

Comment: нашел решение https://pastebin.com/rZ62vhHW

Comment: @performance судя по тому, что ваше решение сработало - вы просто не тот тип передавали в конструктор XmlSerializer - у вас new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parametres)), нужно было new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response)).